# set hardwareaccelerated true in fragment

Tags: android, android-cardview

How can I set hardware-accelerated in the fragment. I used

`window.setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED )` 
but it's not working

Comment: How did you know that it's not working?

Comment: So when I run the app I see cardView not showing correctly